# Can Animals in Animal Crossing New leaf return to town and live there once again?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

my favorite animal, Tom, moved away 3 years ago, how do I get Him back!

Comment: @AlexMyers Does that apply to animals?

Comment: @Joachim Yes. The animals are the villagers.

Comment: @AlexMyers Right..